# MongoDB query with $lookup pipeline hanging and not terminating

Tags: mongodb, lookup, pipeline

I'm trying to ask my database on mongodb for this query:
I want to know all the dogs adopted in 2017. 
In my database i have two Collections, one for Adoption and one for dogs and cats called Ospiti . 
I wanted to use $lookup to mimic a SQL Join for retrieving the species of the animal but I think I am failing in something.

The query that gets stucked while processing is:

Adozione is Adoption
Ospiti is the Collection containing both dogs and cats registred in the animal shelter.
DataAdozione is AdoptionDate.

```
db.Adozione.aggregate([
   {
       $lookup:
            {
                from: "Ospite",
                let: {dataadozione : "$DataAdozione"},
                pipeline: [ {$match: { "Specie":"Cane" } }, 
                        {$match:
                        {$expr:
                            {$and:[
                                {$gte: ["$$dataadozione","2017-01-01"]},
                                {$lte: ["$$dataadozione","2017-12-31"]}
                            ]}
                        }
                         },
                       {$project: {"_id":0, "MatricolaO":1, "Nome":1, "Specie":1, "dataadozione":1 } } ],
                as:"cani"
            }

    },
    {$unwind:"$cani"}

]).pretty()
```

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you mean by "stuck"? Is it just hanging (i.e. not terminating), terminating but not returning expected results, or something else entirely? Being more descriptive about your problem will improve the likelihood of receiving a helpful answer.

Comment: For stuck I mean just hanging and not terminating. Could it be because the query is "too heavy" for my laptopt to process?

Comment: How big are these collections? Are you using indexes? Are these indexes valid for this particular aggregate? These are considerations you'll want to make. It sounds like you're running into a performance issue, where the queries are taking an extraordinarily long time to complete. The above questions concern possible bottlenecks you should be taking a look at. If you have a lot of documents and your queries aren't being optimized through appropriate use of indexes, you're going to run into problems with your queries hanging like this.